# How I can insert name all my categories in firebase?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to insert to my firebase dashboard the name all my categories which all the user in mobile app will see it, but when I import that JSON onto firebase the firebase said to me the import is succeeded but I can't see any categories just my root app equal null.
That my JSON:

```
{
  "categories": {
    "Books": {
      "Accessories": {
        "AddressBooks": {},
        "BookCovers": {},
        "BookLights": {},
        "BookMarks": {},
        "OtherBookAccessories": {}
      },
      "AntiquarianCollectible": {},
      "AudioBooks": {},
      "Catalogues": {},
      "ChildreanYoungAdult": {},
      "CookBooks": {},
      "Fiction": {},
      "Magazine": {},
      "Nonfiction": {},
      "TextBooksEducation": {},
      "OtherBooks": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no data in the objects so Firebase is not saving it... try putting something in the action objects and see if that makes a difference

Comment: It will. The Firebase Database stores values with their associated path. If there is no value, it will immediately delete the path.

Comment: I create some data inside my object it works, but that mean I can't have object have a null value.